# Redirect of http to https remove slash after .com apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

[http link of page](http://ampletrails.com/ds2ce56c0tirp-hd720p-indoor-ir-turret-camera/hikvision-cameras)  when redirect removes the / after the .com

[https link of page but without / after .com](https://ampletrails.comds2ce56c0tirp-hd720p-indoor-ir-turret-camera/hikvision-cameras)

I am using VPS with apache and have following code in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

Comment: The redirect is not result of this rule.

Comment: Complete .htaccess file  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8c3fae6dd05c0345beafc5f89dfc77fe

Comment: Perhaps there is something also worth looking at in VirtualHost configuration?

Comment: Here is the Virtual Host file. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/41627f494d40b20a8e828bbe2e4a737b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `<VirtualHost *:80>`

```
Redirect permanent / https://ampletrails.com
```

should be

```
Redirect permanent / https://ampletrails.com/
```